# Mysql can two foregin keys point to the same primary key

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

I wonder if a mysql table can have two columns that is FK and proints to the same PK in another table like this:

Table **conversations**:

```
          $table->increments('con_id');
          $table->string('subject', 45);
          $table->integer('sender_id')->unsigned()->index();
          $table->integer('recipient_id')->unsigned()->index();
          $table->foreign('sender_id')->references('user_id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
          $table->foreign('recipient_id')->references('user_id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
```

Comment: Yes, it's perfectly fine.

Comment: What problem do you have when you try it?

Comment: @Barmar I dont find any problem I just wonder if it would be an issue later once the table gets bigger, peformance etc :)

Comment: No, this is perfectly normal for tables that relate two items in the same parent table, like conversations or social media friendship.

Comment: @user2722667 You should have no issues

Comment: @Stivan thx for looking it up (not that we didn't know ... but finding it )